# Submit button not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

When I want to submit my question, system tells me "You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.", But I'm pretty sure I didn't asked any question in past 24 hours, not even in past 6 month.

I tried different IPs, even my real IP.

My profile just have one record for my questions. And I cleared any regarding cookies. But not any success, the system insist to not allowing me to submit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing from an IP which is shared by many others( ex; school; workplace) then the system sees all questions from that place originating from that single IP.

Your IP however, seems to point that it's from Stack Overflow, hence the error - I'll have a CM look into this.

Comment: But there is a IP that, I'm sure no one else using it, and that is my VPS IP, which I'm connecting from, it doesn't shared with anyone. I tried it also. (and I think at the first try, it was my IP).
What you mean "my IP point that it's from Stack Overflow"? and what is "CM Look"?

Comment: There is lots of case when user is behind a NAT and his/her IP is shared with others, so identifying users with their IP may not be the best solution, when you can do it with email for the guests, and user ID for the members.

Comment: @2i3r this should be fixed now

Comment: yes, it is. thanks