# why is it telling me always "You can only post once every 5 minutes."

Tags: bug, status-completed

I think it's a bug, but it doesn't allow me to post a question.

You can only post once every 5 minutes.

Comment: strange, seems to be somewhat related to http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7744/submit-button-not-working

Comment: It worked now. Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem too. It did go away probably around the time as you